# trying to get longitude and latitude of a location

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILSuX.png) ok so far this is what I have done 
![Click here] Getting coordinates[Click here]

(-33.674068533741966, 149.86544609069824),(-33.578014746143985, 150.87069511413574),(-34.03445260967646, 149.98080253601074)

these are the coordinates of my selected location
now I want to store these values into an array without any special characters and white-spaces...
secondly I want to store all x coordinates in a separate array and y coordinates in a separate array
kindly help me this...
How should i do this ?

[[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILSuX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILSuX.png)

Comment: please check your images are missing

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @MarinNedea see the image

Comment: @PardeepPathania see the image

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaSarwar see image. this is not an answer to where is your code. Post your code , with which you are working and trying to make it work.

Comment: @Arsh i think ur nt getting my point all i am trying to say is i want to store the location in an array without comma brackets and whitspaces all i want is something like this $location_array[0]=-33.674068533741966 and so one and then i want to store all x cordinates of a point in another array and y cordinates in an another array e.g x_cordianates_array=[-33.674068533741966,-33.578014746143985,-34.03445260967646]

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaSarwar check my answer.

Comment: @Arsh thanks alot brother

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaSarwar  welcome :) . thats just a basic method of doing that. Have fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try the solution below to convert the coordinates into an array and include the values on x and y array.

```
$data = "(-33.674068533741966, 149.86544609069824),(-33.578014746143985, 150.87069511413574),(-34.03445260967646, 149.98080253601074)";
  $data = explode('(',$data);
  $data = str_replace(')','',$data);
  $final_result_x = array();
  $final_result_y = array();
  foreach($data as $d){
    if(empty($d)){
      continue;
    }
    $exploded = explode(',',$d);
    $final_result_x[] = $exploded[0];
    $final_result_y[] = $exploded[1];
  }
    echo '---- Result x ---- <br /><pre>';
    print_r($final_result_x);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '---- Result y ---- <br /><pre>';
    print_r($final_result_y);
    echo '</pre>';
```

output :

```
---- Result x ---- 
Array
(
    [0] => -33.674068533741966
    [1] => -33.578014746143985
    [2] => -34.03445260967646
)
---- Result y ---- 
Array
(
    [0] =>  149.86544609069824
    [1] =>  150.87069511413574
    [2] =>  149.98080253601074
)
```